# how do i upload files based on their format using php

Tags: php

How do I upload files and move them to their perspective folder using php,
I'm trying to make the script automatically upload

images such as jpg and png to jpg/ folder
mp3 to mp3/ folder
and mp4 flv mpeg to mp4 folder

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$jpg = "jpg/";
$mp3 = "mp3/";
$mp4 = "mp4/";


if (!empty($_FILES))
{
  if(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3) == "mp3")
  {
    $destination = substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3);
    $file        =   $_FILES['file']['name'];

    echo "this : " . $mp3,$destination . $ds;
    move_uploaded_file($mp3,$destination . $ds ) or die("mp3 error");
    echo "uploaded : " . $file . "<br>";
  }
  else if(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3) == "mp4" or substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3) == "mp4" or substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -4) == "mpeg" )
  {
    $destination = substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3);
    $file        =   $_FILES['file']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($mp4,$destination . $ds ) or die("mp4 error");
    echo "uploaded : " . $file . "<br>";
  }
  else if(substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3) == "jpg" or substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3) == "png")
  {
    $destination = substr($_FILES['file']['name'], -3);
    $file        =   $_FILES['file']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($jpg,$destination . $ds ) or die("jpg error");
    echo "uploaded : " . $file . "<br>";
  }
  else
  {

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: And what? Your script works or what?

Comment: no it's not working I'm reaching to die() on each format

Comment: `$XXX,$destination . $ds` - there shouldn't be a `$ds` here. That translates to `folder/file.xxx/` resulting in an error.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` takes a tmp file from `$_FILES`, not `mp3` or `jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Read `move_uploaded_file` [manual](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file).

First argument is "The filename of the uploaded file.". And you pass what:

```
move_uploaded_file($mp3,$destination . $ds )
```

`$mp3` is a **folder** `mp3`.

Usually you need to pass `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` as first argument.

Second note - concatenation `$destination . $ds` returns what?

In case of `music.mp3` file it will be `mp3/`.

So you call `move_uploaded_file` with arguments:

```
move_uploaded_file('mp3/', 'mp3/');
```

Do you really want this?

So, the simpliest fix is (for an mp3 case):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $mp3 . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

In this case file will be saved in `mp3` folder on the same level as your script with file's original name.

Also make sure that `mp3` folder **exists** and has **proper permissions**.